# Creating a encrypted Password with BLOWFISH with byte[24] length

Tags: c#, encryption, byte, blowfish

I need to create a encrypted password for a server. This server uses Blowfish encryption to do the encryption. Now here are the info I have:

1. KEY: "12345678abcdefgmypassword"
2. Block size: 8 bytes - 64 bits
3. END BYTES: byte[24]

The data that I want to encrypt is "ABCDEFG12345678".

The problem I am having is to get the encryption that is only 24 bytes max where I get 48 each time.
I think my biggest problem is because I cannot wrap my head around what should happen!

Here is some of my code:

```
>  BlowFish b = new BlowFish("12345678abcdefgmypassword");
>  Here I get the key array of byte[12]
>  plainText = "0123456789ABCDEF";
>  cipherText = b.Encrypt_CBC(plainText);
>  var encodedString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
>  byte[] myByteArray = encodedString.GetBytes(cipherText);
```

Now the questions I have:
1. What is the block size? And how do I use it?
2. How do I get bytes below or equal to byte[24]?

I really hope some of you guys can help my brain begin to go in the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually mean blowfish encryption, or bcrypt hashing?

Comment: I suspect you messed up encoding somewhere.

Comment: Using ASCII on a ciphertext can't be right. If `Encrypt_CBC` returns a hex string, you need to apply hex decoding to it.

Answer (score 0):

A [Block size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) is the amount of data that a Block cipher works on at one time. For example, if a Block size of an encryption algorithm is 128 bits, then in ASCII that would be 16 characters.

To use a block size, you need segment your "plaintext" (text that hasn't been encrypted yet) into 64 bit blocks (in your case). Then cycle each block through the encryption, and concatenate the output. (If you're implementing [ECB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) encryption, which isn't recommended).

As I said above, you need to carve up your text into blocks. The last block might be under the necessary block size, and will need [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29).

Hopefully this puts you on the right lines :)

Comment: How would some of the code look?

> Blowfish b = new Blowfish(hexkey).

How do I get the hex key from "12345678abcdefgmypassword"??

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the source code here http://www.schneier.com/code/blowfish.cs it may help you better understand how this works. Also an excellent book on cryptography which explains the details of how these algorithms work is applied cryptography by schneier found here [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0471117099/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099)

Edit:

Alright I've had time to play with this and I think I know what the problem you're having is. The reason you are ending up with 48 bytes of data instead of 24 is because you are trying to manipulate the string representation of the cyphertext which is 48 bytes long in order to display the entire cyphertext in ASCII. All that you need to do is convert the ascii string representation into a byte array. The catch is (you were on the right track) you must do it in the same way that the encrypt method does. Here is the code to do it:

```
class Program
{
    private static byte[] HexToByte(string hex)
    {
        byte[] r = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            byte a = GetHex(hex[i]);
            byte b = GetHex(hex[i + 1]);
            r[i / 2] = (byte)(a * 16 + b);
        }
        return r;
    }



    private static byte GetHex(char x)
    {
        if (x <= '9' && x >= '0')
        {
            return (byte)(x - '0');
        }
        else if (x <= 'z' && x >= 'a')
        {
            return (byte)(x - 'a' + 10);
        }
        else if (x <= 'Z' && x >= 'A')
        {
            return (byte)(x - 'A' + 10);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlowFish b = new BlowFish("12345678abcdefgmypassword");
        string plainText = "ABCDEFG12345678";
        string cipherText = b.Encrypt_CBC(plainText);
        MessageBox.Show(cipherText);
        plainText = b.Decrypt_CBC(cipherText);
        byte[] myByteArray = HexToByte(cipherText);
        MessageBox.Show(plainText);

    }
}
```

The HexToByte and GetHex methods are copied directly from the Blowfish class that is what is used on  the plaintext when encrypting and decrypting. Note that in CBC mode on a string the IV (initialization vector) is copied to the front of the string so the first 8 bytes are the IV. On a sample run of this code here is what I got.

cipherText is "2866ccafa647d82e7c74e135dbdcb9060cefea39b9b84964" in ascii hex represenation
myByteArray is same except its in byte[24].

I hope this helps man good luck!

Comment: I am currently using the blowfish class but I am not sure what to use where in the code. I seems to me I have to create a hex string from my password string to enter in the code. But that part eludes me!

Comment: @Phillip Kemp From what I see in the class the usage of strings is fine. It's what you do with the ciphertext afterwards that is most likely the problem. How are you sending this data to the server? I'm unclear as to what exactly you're trying to do?